# Is there a way to upload to CloudStorage from a URL?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

There is a public URL pointing to a zipped CSV file.

(Actually about 100 URLs where each zip file is about 250MB and 1.6GB uncompressed)

I would like for this data to be in CloudStorage so I can process it in BigQuery but I obviously don't want to download this to a different server just to turn around a re-upload to CS.

Is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity (if you're willing to share), what public data is this?  We're always looking for big public data sources for demo apps / presentations on BigQuery!

Comment: I'm completely willing to share because it's Google's dataset to begin with. 
http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets
I know there is publicdata.samples.trigrams but I'm specifically interested in the 2-gram dataset and the trigram schema doesn't seem to match the one listed on the ngrams site.

Comment: Here are some other ideas. :-)

http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/

Comment: :)  Just responded to your feedback form note.  We don't have any immediate plans to add to our public data repository, but these still could potentially good demos.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not possible at this time.